# How to do fade-in and fade-out with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I want to make an HTML div tag fade in and fade out.

I have some code that fades out, but when I fade in, the opacity of the div stays at 0.1 and doesn't increase.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Fade to Black</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function slidePanel(elementToSlide, slideSource)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementToSlide);

            if(element.up == null || element.up == false) {
                setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + elementToSlide + "\")", 100);
                element.up = true;
                slideSource.innerHTML = "Bring it down";
            } else {
                setTimeout("fadeIn(\"" + elementToSlide + "\")", 100);
                element.up = false;
                slideSource.innerHTML = "Take it up";
            }
        }

        function fadeIn(elementToFade)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementToFade);

            element.style.opacity += 0.1;
            if(element.style.opacity > 1.0) {
                element.style.opacity = 1.0;
            } else {
                setTimeout("fadeIn(\"" + elementToFade + "\")", 100);
            }
        }

        function fadeOut(elementToFade)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementToFade);

            element.style.opacity -= 0.1;
            if(element.style.opacity < 0.0) {
                element.style.opacity = 0.0;
            } else {
                setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + elementToFade + "\")", 100);
            }
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>
        <div id="slideSource"
              style="width:150px; height:20px;
                    text-align:center; background:green"
             onclick="slidePanel('panel', this)">
            Take It up
        </div>
        <div id="panel"
              style="width:150px; height:130px;
                    text-align:center; background:red;
                    opacity:1.0;">
            Contents
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to fade in and fade out an element?

Comment: Can you explain the fadeIn? There is recursion used, until the opacity has reached one, then the function stops? But there is no return false to exit the func.?

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to do a fade. [CSS can do that way, way more easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760338/1269037).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've worked it out

```
element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```

Should be used instead of

```
element.style.opacity += 0.1;
```

Same with

```
element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity) - 0.1;
```

Instead of

```
element.style.opacity -= 0.1;
```

Because opacity value is stored as string, not as float. I'm still not sure though why the addition has worked.

Comment: You can also use `element.style.opacity = +element.style.opacity + 0.1;`. The unary plus operator converts the string to a number (float in this case)

Comment: You should avoid storing values in the DOM, unless you don't rly care about performance...

Answer (score 155):

Here is **a more efficient way of fading out** an element:

```
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

you can do the reverse for fade in

setInterval or setTimeout should not get a string as argument

google the evils of eval to know why

And here is **a more efficient way of fading in** an element.

```
function unfade(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: how to I make it to fade in?

Comment: @LohnClaidon to fade in, set `op = 0` update the condition to `if(op >= 1)` and change the increment expression at the end to `op += op*0.1`. I have not tested this but i am positive it will work. And of course you remove the `display ='none'` line

Comment: Beware: op is always zero!

Comment: Above, everlasto was talking about how if you set op = 0 for the fadein function, op += op*0.1 is always going to be 0. therefor, set it to a value greater than 0, like 0.1. Hopefully this saves someone a few minutes of time.

Comment: @Nappa300 I'd recommend you post that as a separate answer rather than editing it into the post.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Because of how tied together fadein and fadeout are, the function was derived from this post, and the question asked for both - it should be in the same post.

Comment: As of 2015, I would use [requestAnimationFrame](http://idiallo.com/javascript/using-requestanimationframe) and use setTimeout as a fallback.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to do a fade. [CSS can do that way, way more easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760338/1269037). Why this is the accepted answer boggles my mind.

Comment: What does 'element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";' do?

Comment: @RobertMolina this is the property for opacity on internet explorer. Only add it if you want to support older browsers.

Answer (score 104):

Here is a simplified running example of [Seattle Ninja's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css/17613329#17613329).

```js
var slideSource = document.getElementById('slideSource');

document.getElementById('handle').onclick = function () {
  slideSource.classList.toggle('fade');
}
```

```css
#slideSource {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
}

#slideSource.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="handle">Fade</button> 
<div id="slideSource">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
```

Comment: Great answer!  Upvoted!  Per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495833/2430549), there are two bugs: 1) There are two conflicting CSS property keys, and the choice of the working one is coincidental to Chrome, use `!important`, 2) This answer definitely does not solve the problem where the elements _begin as hidden_. Good otherwise!  Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work if the element starts hidden (display: none).

Comment: Yes, he is right in your code element is still present in the DOM and when you apply display: none property then fades doesn't work.

Answer (score 33):

why do that to yourself?

jQuery:

```
$("#element").fadeOut();
$("#element").fadeIn();
```

I think that's easier.

[www.jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

Comment: Because you dont want to wait on a huge script to load when you only want to fade something in and out.

Comment: @void well, this answer is from 2011, that's a bit before CSS3 was widely adopted, I agree - today it might be more beneficial to do those transitions using CSS and avoid adding code - which is way better.

Comment: Today you can do it with CSS transitions in a better way

Answer (score 15):

Here's my attempt with Javascript and CSS3 animation
So the HTML:

```
 <div id="handle">Fade</div> 
 <div id="slideSource">Whatever you want images or  text here</div>
```

The CSS3 with transitions:

```
div#slideSource {
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
-moz-transition: opacity 3s;     
transition: opacity 3s; 
}

div#slideSource.fade {
opacity:0;
}
```

The Javascript part. Check if the className exists, if it does then add the class and transitions.

```
document.getElementById('handle').onclick = function(){
    if(slideSource.className){
        document.getElementById('slideSource').className = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('slideSource').className = 'fade';
    }
}
```

Just click and it will fade in and out. I would recommend using JQuery as Itai Sagi mentioned. I left out Opera and MS, so I would recommend using prefixr to add that in the css.  This is my first time posting on stackoverflow but it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use these utility functions. `element` is the HTML element and `duration` is the desired duration in milliseconds.

```
export const fadeIn = (element, duration) => {
    (function increment(value = 0) {
        element.style.opacity = String(value);
        if (element.style.opacity !== '1') {
            setTimeout(() => {
                increment(value + 0.1);
            }, duration / 10);
        }
    })();
};

export const fadeOut = (element, duration) => {
    (function decrement() {
        (element.style.opacity -= 0.1) < 0 ? element.style.display = 'none' : setTimeout(() => {
            decrement();
        }, duration / 10);
    })();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres my code for a fade in/out toggle functions.

```
fadeIn: function (len) {
                var obj = this.e;
                obj.style.display = '';
                var op = 0; 
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (op >= 1 || op >= 1.0){
                        console.log('done', op)
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                    obj.style.opacity = op.toFixed(1);
                    op += 0.1;
                    console.log(obj.style.opacity);
                }, len);
                return this;
            },
    fadeOut: function (len) {
                var obj = this.e;
                var op = 1; 
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (op <= 0){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        console.log('done', op)
                        obj.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    obj.style.opacity = op.toFixed(1);
                    op -= 0.1;
                    console.log(obj.style.opacity)
                }, len);
                return this;
            },
```

This was from a jQuery style lib i did. hope it's helpfull. link to lib on cloud9:
https://c9.io/christopherdumas/magik_wb

Answer (score 1):

I like Ibu's one but, I think I have a better solution using his idea.

```
//Fade In.
element.style.opacity = 0;
var Op1 = 0;
var Op2 = 1;
var foo1, foo2;
foo1 = setInterval(Timer1, 20);
function Timer1()
{
    element.style.opacity = Op1;
    Op1 = Op1 + .01;
    console.log(Op1); //Option, but I recommend it for testing purposes.
    if (Op1 > 1)
    {
        clearInterval(foo1);
        foo2 = setInterval(Timer3, 20);
    }
}
```

This solution uses a additional equation unlike Ibu's solution, which used a multiplicative equation. The way it works is it takes a time increment (t), an opacity increment (o), and a opacity limit (l) in the equation, which is: (T = time of fade in miliseconds) [T = (l/o)*t]. the "20" represents the time increments or intervals (t), the ".01" represents the opacity increments (o), and the 1 represents the opacity limit (l). When you plug the numbers in the equation you get 2000 milliseconds (or 2 seconds). Here is the console log:

```
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.060000000000000005
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.09999999999999999
0.10999999999999999
0.11999999999999998
0.12999999999999998
0.13999999999999999
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18000000000000002
0.19000000000000003
0.20000000000000004
0.21000000000000005
0.22000000000000006
0.23000000000000007
0.24000000000000007
0.25000000000000006
0.26000000000000006
0.2700000000000001
0.2800000000000001
0.2900000000000001
0.3000000000000001
0.3100000000000001
0.3200000000000001
0.3300000000000001
0.34000000000000014
0.35000000000000014
0.36000000000000015
0.37000000000000016
0.38000000000000017
0.3900000000000002
0.4000000000000002
0.4100000000000002
0.4200000000000002
0.4300000000000002
0.4400000000000002
0.45000000000000023
0.46000000000000024
0.47000000000000025
0.48000000000000026
0.49000000000000027
0.5000000000000002
0.5100000000000002
0.5200000000000002
0.5300000000000002
0.5400000000000003
0.5500000000000003
0.5600000000000003
0.5700000000000003
0.5800000000000003
0.5900000000000003
0.6000000000000003
0.6100000000000003
0.6200000000000003
0.6300000000000003
0.6400000000000003
0.6500000000000004
0.6600000000000004
0.6700000000000004
0.6800000000000004
0.6900000000000004
0.7000000000000004
0.7100000000000004
0.7200000000000004
0.7300000000000004
0.7400000000000004
0.7500000000000004
0.7600000000000005
0.7700000000000005
0.7800000000000005
0.7900000000000005
0.8000000000000005
0.8100000000000005
0.8200000000000005
0.8300000000000005
0.8400000000000005
0.8500000000000005
0.8600000000000005
0.8700000000000006
0.8800000000000006
0.8900000000000006
0.9000000000000006
0.9100000000000006
0.9200000000000006
0.9300000000000006
0.9400000000000006
0.9500000000000006
0.9600000000000006
0.9700000000000006
0.9800000000000006
0.9900000000000007
1.0000000000000007
1.0100000000000007
```

Notice how the opacity follows the opacity increment amount of .01 just like in the code. If you use the code Ibu made,

```
//I made slight edits but keeped the ESSENTIAL stuff in it.
var op = 0.01;  // initial opacity
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op >= 1){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    op += op * 0.1;
}, 20);
```

you will get these numbers (or something similar) in you console log. Here is what I got.

```
0.0101
0.010201
0.01030301
0.0104060401
0.010510100501
0.010615201506009999
0.0107213535210701
0.0108285670562808
0.010936852726843608
0.011046221254112044
0.011156683466653165
0.011268250301319695
0.011380932804332892
0.01149474213237622
0.011609689553699983
0.011725786449236983
0.011843044313729352
0.011961474756866645
0.012081089504435313
0.012201900399479666
0.012323919403474463
0.012447158597509207
0.0125716301834843
0.012697346485319142
0.012824319950172334
0.012952563149674056
0.013082088781170797
0.013212909668982505
0.01334503876567233
0.013478489153329052
0.013613274044862343
0.013749406785310966
0.013886900853164076
0.014025769861695717
0.014166027560312674
0.014307687835915801
0.01445076471427496
0.01459527236141771
0.014741225085031886
0.014888637335882205
0.015037523709241028
0.015187898946333437
0.01533977793579677
0.015493175715154739
0.015648107472306286
0.01580458854702935
0.015962634432499644
0.01612226077682464
0.016283483384592887
0.016446318218438817
0.016610781400623206
0.01677688921462944
0.016944658106775732
0.01711410468784349
0.017285245734721923
0.017458098192069144
0.017632679173989835
0.01780900596572973
0.01798709602538703
0.018166966985640902
0.01834863665549731
0.018532123022052285
0.018717444252272807
0.018904618694795535
0.01909366488174349
0.019284601530560927
0.019477447545866538
0.0196722220213252
0.019868944241538455
0.02006763368395384
0.02026831002079338
0.020470993121001313
0.020675703052211326
0.02088246008273344
0.021091284683560776
0.021302197530396385
0.02151521950570035
0.021730371700757353
0.021947675417764927
0.022167152171942577
0.022388823693662
0.022612711930598623
0.022838839049904608
0.023067227440403654
0.02329789971480769
0.023530878711955767
0.023766187499075324
0.024003849374066077
0.02424388786780674
0.024486326746484807
0.024731190013949654
0.024978501914089152
0.025228286933230044
0.025480569802562344
0.025735375500587968
0.025992729255593847
0.026252656548149785
0.026515183113631283
0.026780334944767597
0.027048138294215273
0.027318619677157426
0.027591805873929
0.02786772393266829
0.028146401171994972
0.028427865183714922
0.02871214383555207
0.02899926527390759
0.029289257926646668
0.029582150505913136
0.029877972010972267
0.030176751731081992
0.030478519248392812
0.03078330444087674
0.031091137485285508
0.031402048860138365
0.03171606934873975
0.03203323004222715
0.03235356234264942
0.03267709796607591
0.03300386894573667
0.03333390763519403
0.03366724671154597
0.03400391917866143
0.03434395837044805
0.03468739795415253
0.03503427193369406
0.035384614653031
0.035738460799561306
0.03609584540755692
0.03645680386163249
0.03682137190024882
0.03718958561925131
0.03756148147544382
0.03793709629019826
0.03831646725310024
0.038699631925631243
0.03908662824488755
0.039477494527336426
0.03987226947260979
0.040270992167335894
0.04067370208900925
0.04108043910989934
0.04149124350099834
0.04190615593600832
0.042325217495368404
0.04274846967032209
0.04317595436702531
0.04360771391069556
0.044043791049802515
0.04448422896030054
0.04492907124990354
0.04537836196240258
0.045832145582026605
0.04629046703784687
0.04675337170822534
0.047220905425307595
0.04769311447956067
0.04817004562435628
0.04865174608059984
0.04913826354140584
0.0496296461768199
0.0501259426385881
0.05062720206497398
0.05113347408562372
0.05164480882647996
0.05216125691474476
0.05268286948389221
0.053209698178731134
0.05374179516051845
0.05427921311212363
0.05482200524324487
0.05537022529567732
0.05592392754863409
0.056483166824120426
0.05704799849236163
0.05761847847728525
0.0581946632620581
0.05877660989467868
0.059364375993625464
0.05995801975356172
0.060557599951097336
0.06116317595060831
0.06177480771011439
0.06239255578721554
0.0630164813450877
0.06364664615853857
0.06428311262012396
0.0649259437463252
0.06557520318378844
0.06623095521562633
0.0668932647677826
0.06756219741546042
0.06823781938961503
0.06892019758351117
0.06960939955934628
0.07030549355493974
0.07100854849048914
0.07171863397539403
0.07243582031514798
0.07316017851829945
0.07389178030348245
0.07463069810651728
0.07537700508758245
0.07613077513845827
0.07689208288984285
0.07766100371874128
0.0784376137559287
0.07922198989348798
0.08001420979242287
0.0808143518903471
0.08162249540925057
0.08243872036334307
0.0832631075669765
0.08409573864264626
0.08493669602907272
0.08578606298936345
0.08664392361925709
0.08751036285544966
0.08838546648400417
0.08926932114884421
0.09016201436033265
0.09106363450393598
0.09197427084897535
0.0928940135574651
0.09382295369303975
0.09476118322997015
0.09570879506226986
0.09666588301289256
0.09763254184302148
0.0986088672614517
0.09959495593406621
0.10059090549340688
0.10159681454834095
0.10261278269382436
0.1036389105207626
0.10467529962597022
0.10572205262222992
0.10677927314845222
0.10784706587993674
0.10892553653873611
0.11001479190412347
0.1111149398231647
0.11222608922139635
0.11334835011361032
0.11448183361474643
0.11562665195089389
0.11678291847040283
0.11795074765510685
0.11913025513165793
0.1203215576829745
0.12152477325980425
0.12274002099240229
0.12396742120232632
0.12520709541434957
0.12645916636849308
0.127723758032178
0.12900099561249978
0.13029100556862477
0.13159391562431103
0.13290985478055414
0.1342389533283597
0.13558134286164328
0.1369371562902597
0.1383065278531623
0.13968959313169393
0.14108648906301088
0.142497353953641
0.1439223274931774
0.14536155076810917
0.14681516627579025
0.14828331793854815
0.14976615111793362
0.15126381262911295
0.15277645075540408
0.15430421526295812
0.1558472574155877
0.15740572998974356
0.158979787289641
0.1605695851625374
0.16217528101416276
0.16379703382430438
0.16543500416254742
0.1670893542041729
0.16876024774621462
0.17044785022367676
0.17215232872591352
0.17387385201317265
0.17561259053330439
0.17736871643863744
0.1791424036030238
0.18093382763905405
0.1827431659154446
0.18457059757459904
0.18641630355034502
0.1882804665858485
0.19016327125170698
0.19206490396422404
0.19398555300386627
0.19592540853390494
0.197884662619244
0.19986350924543644
0.20186214433789082
0.20388076578126973
0.20591957343908243
0.20797876917347324
0.21005855686520797
0.21215914243386005
0.21428073385819865
0.21642354119678064
0.21858777660874845
0.22077365437483593
0.2229813909185843
0.22521120482777013
0.22746331687604782
0.2297379500448083
0.23203532954525638
0.23435568284070896
0.23669923966911605
0.2390662320658072
0.24145689438646528
0.24387146333032994
0.24631017796363325
0.24877327974326957
0.25126101254070227
0.2537736226661093
0.2563113588927704
0.2588744724816981
0.26146321720651505
0.2640778493785802
0.266718627872366
0.26938581415108964
0.27207967229260055
0.27480046901552657
0.27754847370568186
0.28032395844273866
0.28312719802716607
0.28595847000743774
0.2888180547075121
0.2917062352545872
0.2946232976071331
0.2975695305832044
0.3005452258890364
0.3035506781479268
0.3065861849294061
0.3096520467787002
0.3127485672464872
0.31587605291895204
0.31903481344814155
0.322225161582623
0.3254474131984492
0.3287018873304337
0.33198890620373805
0.33530879526577545
0.3386618832184332
0.34204850205061754
0.3454689870711237
0.34892367694183496
0.35241291371125333
0.35593704284836586
0.3594964132768495
0.363091377409618
0.3667222911837142
0.3703895140955513
0.37409340923650686
0.37783434332887195
0.38161268676216065
0.38542881362978226
0.3892831017660801
0.3931759327837409
0.3971076921115783
0.40107876903269407
0.405089556723021
0.4091404522902512
0.4132318568131537
0.41736417538128523
0.4215378171350981
0.42575319530644906
0.43001072725951356
0.43431083453210867
0.43865394287742976
0.4430404823062041
0.44747088712926614
0.4519455960005588
0.45646505196056436
0.46102970248017
0.4656399995049717
0.47029639950002144
0.47499936349502164
0.47974935712997185
0.48454685070127157
0.4893923192082843
0.4942862424003671
0.4992291048243708
0.5042213958726145
0.5092636098313407
0.5143562459296541
0.5194998083889507
0.5246948064728402
0.5299417545375685
0.5352411720829442
0.5405935838037736
0.5459995196418114
0.5514595148382295
0.5569741099866118
0.5625438510864779
0.5681692895973427
0.5738509824933161
0.5795894923182493
0.5853853872414317
0.5912392411138461
0.5971516335249846
0.6031231498602344
0.6091543813588367
0.615245925172425
0.6213983844241493
0.6276123682683908
0.6338884919510748
0.6402273768705855
0.6466296506392913
0.6530959471456843
0.6596269066171412
0.6662231756833126
0.6728854074401457
0.6796142615145472
0.6864104041296927
0.6932745081709896
0.7002072532526995
0.7072093257852266
0.7142814190430788
0.7214242332335097
0.7286384755658448
0.7359248603215033
0.7432841089247183
0.7507169500139654
0.7582241195141051
0.7658063607092461
0.7734644243163386
0.7811990685595019
0.789011059245097
0.7969011698375479
0.8048701815359234
0.8129188833512826
0.8210480721847955
0.8292585529066434
0.8375511384357098
0.8459266498200669
0.8543859163182677
0.8629297754814503
0.8715590732362648
0.8802746639686274
0.8890774106083137
0.8979681847143969
0.9069478665615408
0.9160173452271562
0.9251775186794278
0.9344292938662221
0.9437735868048843
0.9532113226729332
0.9627434358996625
0.9723708702586591
0.9820945789612456
0.9919155247508581
1.0018346799983666
1.0118530267983503
```

Notice that there is no discernible pattern. If you ran Ibu's code, you would never know how long the fade was. You would have to grab a timer and guess and check 2 seconds. Nonetheless, Ibu's code did make a pretty nice fade in (it probably works for fade out. I don't know because I didn't use a fade out yet). My code will also work for a fade out. Let's just say you wanted 2 seconds for a fade out. You can do that with my code. Here is how it would look:

```
//Fade out. (Continued from the fade in.
function Timer2()
{
    element.style.opacity = Op2;
    Op2 = Op2 - .01;
    console.log(Op2); //Option, but I recommend it for testing purposes.
    if (Op2 < 0)
    { 
        clearInterval(foo2);
    }
}
```

All I did was change the opacity to 1 (or fully opaque). I changed the opacity increment to -.01 so it would start turning invisible. Lastly, I changed the opacity limit to 0. When it hits the opacity limit, the timer will stop. Same as the last one, except it used 1 instead of 0. When you run the code, here is what the console log should relatively look like.

```
.99
0.98
0.97
0.96
0.95
0.94
0.9299999999999999
0.9199999999999999
0.9099999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.8899999999999999
0.8799999999999999
0.8699999999999999
0.8599999999999999
0.8499999999999999
0.8399999999999999
0.8299999999999998
0.8199999999999998
0.8099999999999998
0.7999999999999998
0.7899999999999998
0.7799999999999998
0.7699999999999998
0.7599999999999998
0.7499999999999998
0.7399999999999998
0.7299999999999998
0.7199999999999998
0.7099999999999997
0.6999999999999997
0.6899999999999997
0.6799999999999997
0.6699999999999997
0.6599999999999997
0.6499999999999997
0.6399999999999997
0.6299999999999997
0.6199999999999997
0.6099999999999997
0.5999999999999996
0.5899999999999996
0.5799999999999996
0.5699999999999996
0.5599999999999996
0.5499999999999996
0.5399999999999996
0.5299999999999996
0.5199999999999996
0.5099999999999996
0.49999999999999956
0.48999999999999955
0.47999999999999954
0.46999999999999953
0.4599999999999995
0.4499999999999995
0.4399999999999995
0.4299999999999995
0.4199999999999995
0.4099999999999995
0.39999999999999947
0.38999999999999946
0.37999999999999945
0.36999999999999944
0.35999999999999943
0.3499999999999994
0.3399999999999994
0.3299999999999994
0.3199999999999994
0.3099999999999994
0.2999999999999994
0.28999999999999937
0.27999999999999936
0.26999999999999935
0.25999999999999934
0.24999999999999933
0.23999999999999932
0.22999999999999932
0.2199999999999993
0.2099999999999993
0.1999999999999993
0.18999999999999928
0.17999999999999927
0.16999999999999926
0.15999999999999925
0.14999999999999925
0.13999999999999924
0.12999999999999923
0.11999999999999923
0.10999999999999924
0.09999999999999924
0.08999999999999925
0.07999999999999925
0.06999999999999926
0.059999999999999255
0.04999999999999925
0.03999999999999925
0.02999999999999925
0.019999999999999248
0.009999999999999247
-7.528699885739343e-16
-0.010000000000000753
```

As you can see, the .01 pattern still exists in the fade out. Both fades are smooth and precise. I hope these codes helped you or gave you insight on the topic. If you have any additions or suggestions let me know. Thank you for taking the time to view this!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on [Gb01's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760338/2430549) (thank you!).  I wanted to abstract out the logic so that we could simply pass an element to a function and have that element fade toggle, fade in, or fade out.

#### POD

To use the code below:

- Elements that can be faded should be given the `fadeable` class.
- Fade in/out with `fadeInElement(element)` and `fadeOutElement(element)`.
- Turn fade on/off with toggle, `toggleElementFade(element)`.

#### Improvements Over Gb01's answer

- Bug Fix: Gb01's answer only worked because `id`-based CSS rules take precedence over `class`-based CSS rules, and if you removed `#slideSource` from `#slideSource.fade`, it would cease to work.
- Bug Fix: Gb01's answer provides for when you start with the element displayed.  What if you want to start with it hidden?  Completely different code is required

#### Code: Elements Begin Being Displayed

```js
function fadeInElement(element) {
  element.classList.remove('fade');
}

function fadeOutElement(element) {
  element.classList.add('fade');
}

function toggleElementFade(element) {
  element.classList.toggle('fade');
}

document.getElementById('fade-toggle').onclick = function () {
    toggleElementFade(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}

document.getElementById('fade-in').onclick = function () {
    fadeInElement(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}

document.getElementById('fade-out').onclick = function () {
    fadeOutElement(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}
```

```css
.fadeable {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="fade-toggle">Fade Toggle</button> 
<button id="fade-in">Fade In</button> 
<button id="fade-out">Fade Out</button> 
<div class="fadeable">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
```

#### Code: Elements Begin Being Hidden

```js
function fadeInElement(element) {
  element.style.removeProperty('display');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('fade');
  }, 10);
}

function fadeOutElement(element) {
  element.classList.add('fade');
}

function toggleElementFade(element) {
  element.style.removeProperty('display');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.toggle('fade');
  }, 10);
}

document.getElementById('fade-toggle').onclick = function () {
  toggleElementFade(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}

document.getElementById('fade-in').onclick = function () {
  fadeInElement(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}

document.getElementById('fade-out').onclick = function () {
  fadeOutElement(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeable')[0]);
}
```

```css
    .fadeable {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 1s; 
    }

    .fade {
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<button id="fade-toggle">Fade Toggle</button> 
<button id="fade-in">Fade In</button> 
<button id="fade-out">Fade Out</button> 
<div class="fadeable fade" style="display:none;">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i get the problem :

Once you make the div fade out you aren't exiting the function : fadeout calls itself again over even after opacity has become 0

```
if(element.style.opacity < 0.0) {
            return;
        }
```

And do the same for fadein too

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count=0;
    let text = document.getElementById('heading');
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(count%2==0){
            text.style.opacity="0.1";
            unfade(text);
       text.innerText="Welcome to Javascript </>"; 
            text.style.color="forestgreen";
                }//end of if
        else{   text.style.opacity="0.1";
            unfade(text);
            text.innerText="Hello javascript"; 
             text.style.color="blueviolet";
}//end of else
        count++;//for toggling the text
    });
    //function for fade effect--------
    function unfade(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 30);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:blueviolet" id="heading">Hello javascript</h1>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript will fade in an element from opacity 0 to whatever the opacity value was at the time of calling fade in. You can also set the duration of the animation which is nice:

```
    function fadeIn(element) {
        var duration = 0.5;
        var interval = 10;//ms
        var op = 0.0;
        var iop = element.style.opacity;
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op >= iop) {
                op = iop;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            op += iop/((1000/interval)*duration);
        }, interval);
    }
```

*Based on [IBUs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121270/2057171) but modified to account for previous opacity value and ability to set duration, also removed irrelevant CSS changes it was making

Answer (score 0):

Using js `transitionend` event, e.g., like this:

create css transition with visibility/opacity

```css
.element {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.element.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 4s;
}
```

You control the speed of fading in/out by css transition timing,

next, in js

```js
let o = document.querySelector('.element');

o.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
  if(!e.target.classList.contains('show')) {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

function fadeIn() {
  o.style.display = 'block';
  // setTimeout is important bcs js - https://youtu.be/FSs_JYwnAdI
  setTimeout(e => o.classList.add('show'), 0);
}

function fadeOut() {
  o.classList.remove('show');
}
```

This could be improved tho.

Demo:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        .element {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 1s;
        }

        .element.show {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 4s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="display: flex; gap: 5px; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 5px;">

        <div class="element show" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: black; color: white;">
            I'm faded
        </div>

        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>

    </div>

    <button id="fade-in-btn">fade in</button>
    <button id="fade-out-btn">fade out</button>

    <script>
        let o = document.querySelector('.element');

        o.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
            if (!e.target.classList.contains('show')) {
                e.target.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        function fadeIn() {
            o.style.display = 'block';
            // setTimeout is important bcs js - https://youtu.be/FSs_JYwnAdI
            setTimeout(e => o.classList.add('show'), 0);
        }

        function fadeOut() {
            o.classList.remove('show');
        }

        document.getElementById('fade-in-btn').addEventListener('click', fadeIn);
        document.getElementById('fade-out-btn').addEventListener('click', fadeOut);
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Old question, ik, there is propably a ton of better solutions but wanted to share anyway

Answer (score -1):

That was actually quite simple .

for ex: if you are hiding the text or changing it's color .

```
document.getElementById('availabletoday').style.color = '#f4f6f7';
```

make a css property like this

```
#availabletoday{
       transition: 1s;
    }
```

depending upon your event listener when the JavaScript executes it will transition in 1s . really easy to change the delay .

Let me know if this helps