# Add a fadeIn to a switch from hide to block display

Tags: javascript, onclick, fadein

I have a

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('massage').style.display = 'block';">Button</a>
```

And I want to add a fadeIn to the function, but dont know how.

Comment: See this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/6121203/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. A css3 opacity animation - only suitable for HTML5 enabled browsers i.e. IE9+. Apply this by adding the css class fade to your element.

   .fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

2.) Use jquerys fadein function. Which supports older browsers.

```
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
```

You will need to learn jQuery of course if you don't know it but this is worth doing I think.

Hope that helps

Comment: 3. Create a fade animation in pure JS :)