# FadeIn animation for div with display:none property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues implementing a fadeIn function for one of my div tags that has a display:none property attached to it.

What would be the best way to go about having the div tag appear and then fade in? I am pretty adamant about keeping the display:none property.

This is what I have tried:

```
<div class="graphs_line_based clearfix" style="display:none" id = "test_id">
```

And then in my .script file:

```
document.getElementById('test_id').fadeIn(1000);
```

It simply does not play the animation. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use the jQuery function, `.fadeIn`, you have to call refer to the DOM object like this:

```
$('#test_id').fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: That was it. Silly of me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to say:

```
$("#test_id").fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this solution if you want use javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css)

```
<div class="graphs_line_based clearfix" style="display:block" id = "test_id">aiuto</div>

fade(document.getElementById('test_id'));

function fade(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >=1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            //element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```