# Fade out div after X amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a piece of code that will fade out a couple of div elements after a certain amount of time. Here's an example of what I'm working with at the moment:

```
<div id="CoverPop-cover" class="splash">
<div id="CoverPop-content" class="splash-center">
<img src="../Logo_Script.gif">
</div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for all of the information contained within this code to fade out after 5 seconds.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`. WTP?

Comment: @l'L'l That doesn't explain how to delay the start of the fadeout.

Comment: @Barmar, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6121270/499581) within that question or the last one should.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$("#CoverPop-cover").delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this , fade out all div after x second, here i suppose x equals to one second
so . 1 second = 1000 ms 
you can change the second parameter to setTimout function in order to change "X" second

```
 setTimeout(function(){
$("div").fadeOut(300);}
,1000);
```

Comment: The parameter to the fadeOut() function is the duration of the animation, not the amount of time before it is executed.

Comment: sorry i missed timeout function