# How to add fade in and fade out effect in CSS animations no javascript?

Tags: css, html

I have this [demo in code](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pjgzBg) pen I want to add a fade in effect and a fade out effect to the floating boxes, but every-time I add ".webkit-animation: fadein" or fadeout the animation for the element stops working.

e.g.

```
-webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do fade-in and fade-out with JavaScript and CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css)

Comment: I want to do it in pure CSS sir no JavaScript.  If you look at my example at code pen its pure CSS

Comment: css transitions are the way to go. Use scale and opacity as parameter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrc8m/ Javascript is used only for click event and not any animation. By the way, JS is sexy. :)

Comment: :( I already have a complete css that handles the animation from start to finish,  but I dont know how to modify it to have a fadein and fadeout effect everytime.  If you look at the code here http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pjgzBg it starts and ends as intended but when I add a fadeout and fadein .webkit-animation: fadein the element being animated does not move

Comment: how do you expect fade in to happen. you haven't provided a event propogation element for css or js. Need element for something like hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to define your animations simultaneously. You cannot simply define `-webkit-animation: fadein 5s;` in one of the nth-child divs because this will override the square animation you set on the `li`s themselves.

Additionally, try defining the `fadein` and `fadeout` animations like you defined the square one:

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I edited your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbWEQv?editors=110. It has the `square` animation working in tandem with the `fadein` and `fadeout` animations, though you'll need to fix the timing because each square has special timing and I didn't change them all individually.

The main things to look at are the new fadein/out definitions that I made at the bottom of the css, and the code on lines 155 and 156:

```
-webkit-animation: fadein 12s infinite, square 24s infinite, fadeout 12s 12s infinite;
animation:         fadein 12s infinite, square 24s infinite, fadeout 12s 12s infinite;
```