# Top Notification Bar Show and Hide with smooth effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

In case of any error/warning from my server, I need to show and hide Top Notification Bar with absolute position - DIV.

I need to show this BAR only when the error occurs and hide it after say few seconds may be 10 sec, and with smooth effects?

How can one implement this in HTML, CSS/SCSS and Pure Javascript. NO Javscript Frameworks :(

```
<div id="app-notification-bar" class="app-notification-bar app-error-message"></div>
```

SCSS, prefix is app-

```
.#{$prefix}error-message {
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        vertical-align:central;
        color: #cc0000;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .#{$prefix}notification-bar {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 101;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2.5;
        overflow: hidden; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
        -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
        box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }

    .cssanimations.csstransforms .#{$prefix}notification-bar {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 2.5s 10.0s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 2.5s 10.0s 1 ease forwards;
    }
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('app-notification-bar').innerHTML = wrnMsg;
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('app-notification-bar').innerHTML = ''; }, 3000);
```

Comment: My Bad. I've written the code. Let me share it.

Comment: nvm you added your code... my bad and there are some answers already so I do not need to give my input :) good luck

Comment: you should refer this ans already suits your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
var d;
function error(message){
var d=document.getElementById("error");
d.innerHTML=message;
d.style.opacity="1";
window.setTimeout(function(){
d.style.opacity="0";
},5000);
}
error("a big bug");
```

Css:

```
#error{
opacity:0;
transition:all ease 2s;
background-color:red;
color:white;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [This Out](http://jsfiddle.net/tj1tLdjw/)

CSS

```
body {
  background: white;
}

div.error-content {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  top:-70px;
  position:absolute;
}

div.error-content.active {
  top:0px
}

#showError {
  position: absolute;
 top: 80px; 
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("showError").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var className = document.getElementsByClassName('error-content')[0].className 
  document.getElementsByClassName('error-content')[0].className = className.concat(" active");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('error-content')[0].className = 'error-content'
  },2000)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write your code to as this question.
This can be helpful for you use fadeIn with time and slow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button>Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just replace your loading div with these colouful boxes

Comment: I'm not suppose to use any framework including JQuery