# CSS JS transition in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a slider in my code, it's need to be transition, but it doesn't work.

Here is the JS code
It's also not working in CSS...
It needs to be transitioning when the image is changing. I need a slow changing of images in my slider.

actually I tried this in js:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.transition = "5s ease";
```

Here is HTML

```
        <div class="photo_div">
            <img id="img" src="">
        </div>
        <button onclick="prev()">PREV</button>
        <button onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
```

Here is JS

```js
var names = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];
var index = 0;

function init() {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "photo/" + names[index];
    autoSlide();
}

function next() {
    index++;
    if (index == names.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("img").src = "photo/" + names[index];
    

}

function prev() {

    if (index == 0) {
        index = names.length
    }
    index--;

    document.getElementById("img").src = "photo/" + names[index];

}

function autoSlide() {
    if (index < names.length) {
        setInterval(function() {
         next();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the part HTML code

Comment: What sort of effect are you trying to achieve through the transition? fade transition? side transition?

Comment: simple transition:  transition = "5s ease";

Comment: it's need to be transition when the image is changing, I need a slow changing of images in my slider

Comment: @VCF  Transition happen when the text is changing. Refer link this jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/kcwu006e/4/. lf you do with image, you should be proload images(that will cached) for perfect transition.

Answer (score 0):

In the next and prev functions fade out the image - and set queuing to true, then change the image, then fade the img tag back in.

You can try the following for next, and something similar for prev:

```js
function next() {
    index++;
    if (index == names.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    
    $('#img').fadeOut("slow", "linear", function(){
      document.getElementById("img").src = "photo/" + names[index];
       $('#img').fadeIn("slow", "linear");
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you can't use jQuery, maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css).

Comment: you mean by Jquery?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to use CSS only...is it possible? or only jQuery?

Comment: See my update - it uses callbacks instead of queuing but I think that is simpler.

Comment: What do you want to see while it is changing?

Comment: the next image at once

Comment: I'm confused, what was wrong with your original code?

Comment: I don't want to see background while the image is slowly changing, is it possible?

Comment: sure it is possible, but I don't understand what you want to see.

Comment: I want to see the next image is fading in behind the fading out image, without background seeing

Comment: Position another img behind this one, and then fade this one out.

Comment: where should I position another img? another slider behind this one?