# JavaScript load images with specific duration

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, load, settimeout

I have two arrays : The first with images paths and the second is with different duration and I am trying using the following functions to set dynamically the 'setTimeout' of my 'changeImage()' function as follow:

```
            function changeImage(){
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            img.src = images[x];
            var ztme = tme[x];
            x++;

            if(x >= images.length){
                x = 0;
            } 

            fadeImg(img, 100, true);
            setTimeout("changeImage()",ztme ); //This is the problem!
        }

        function fadeImg(el, val, fade){
            if(fade === true){
                val--;
            }else{
                val ++;
            }

            if(val > 0 && val < 100){
                el.style.opacity = val / 100;
                setTimeout(function(){fadeImg(el, val, fade);}, 10);
            }
        }

        var images = [],
        x = 0;
        images[0] = "daki/eco_pic.jpg";
        images[1] = "daki/art_tnt.gif";
        images[2] = "daki/mkv_uk.jpg";
        images[3] = "daki/bolo_trt.jpg";
        images[4] = "daki/folo_fr.jpg";

        var tme = [], //values of 'Time' for a picture to stay displayed
        tme[0]= 10000; 
        tme[1]= 50000; 
        tme[2]= 2000;
        tme[3]= 30000;
        tme[4]= 5000;
        setTimeout("changeImage()", 15000);
```

If I give a fixed number for the timeout everything is working like a charm. Therefore to set it dynamically generates just errors.

Any idea to let this changeImage() function get dynamically the time?
Am gratefull to any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please hit the `<>` and create a [mcve] and click TIDY before saving. Had you done that, you would have found the typo. Remove the comma in this statement `var tme = [], //values of 'Time' for a picture to stay displayed`

Comment: You also need to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your tme array is not properly initialized.you should used semi column after its declaration;

```
    var tme = []; //<= 
    tme[0]= 10000; 
    tme[1]= 50000; 
    tme[2]= 2000;
    tme[3]= 30000;
    tme[4]= 5000;
    setTimeout("changeImage()", 15000);
```