# Rewriting this Jquery function as plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems rewriting this slideshow function in Javascript. Because of some project constraints, I have to revert back to plain JS.

```
$(".fadein img:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".fadein :eq(0)").fadeOut(2000)
      .next().fadeIn(1000)
      .end().appendTo('.fadein');
  }, 240000)
```

Comment: SO is not a free code translation service. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start for you.

Take a look at: [How to do fade-in and fade-out with JavaScript and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css)

And please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```js
let fadeInImgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.fadein>img:not(:first-child)');
let fadeInElement = document.querySelector('.fadein:first-child');
const fadeOut = function(element, interval) {
  var op = 1; // initial opacity
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, interval);
}
const fadeIn = function(element, interval) {
  var op = 0.1; // initial opacity
  element.style.display = 'block';
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, interval);
}
fadeInImgElements.forEach(function(img) {
  img.style.display = "none";
})
setInterval(function() {
  fadeOut(fadeInElement, 50);
  fadeIn(fadeInElement.nextElementSibling, 50);
  document.querySelector('.fadein').appendChild(fadeInElement.nextElementSibling);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
  <img alt='fadeInImg' src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190406/ourmid/pngtree-img-file-document-icon-png-image_919866.jpg">
  <img alt='fadeInImg' src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190406/ourmid/pngtree-img-file-document-icon-png-image_919866.jpg">
</div>
```